# javascript onload event does not firing on iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

`<body onload="javascript function">` is working well on desktop browser, but is not working on iPhone. My iPhone seems like it can read external CSS files and JS files, since when I click button from page, it fires JS functions. But oddly, only `onload` event is not working. I am so clueless now. Can anybody tell me why can't I fire onload event on iPhone? Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 연습</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=480, user-scalable=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/test1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/fbsdk.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/initcss.js"></script>
        <script>
            //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkLoginCase, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="checkLoginCase()">
        <div id="wrap">
            <header id="top">
                <img src="../fbimg/logo.png" alt="상단이미지" title="상단이미지">
            </header>
        </div>
        <button onclick="checkLoginCase()"> check fxn1</button>
        <button onclick="checkAlert()"> check fxn2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: let me check... my iOS version is 5.0.1

Comment: does your code also work using Safari on your desktop or if you access this page with the ipad's Safari (not in an UIWebView, with the ipad stand-alone browser)?

Comment: Turn on mobile safari developer mode (In Settings -> mobile safari) to see if any error found in the script. Script error may break the onload event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be working, but try to avoid inline JavaScripts.

Try this:

```
window.onload = (function(){
    checkLoginCase();
});

//-or-

window.onload = checkLoginCase;
```

Comment: That is strange. Maybe there are other problems in your code.

Comment: ewww... it was working fine. I didn't set defalut case in switch(){ case } so the page seemed not firing any function.

Comment: @SehoLee - But why it was working on your desktop? (just curious)

Comment: well.. desktop had localstorage data and iphone had not. desktop definately went to switch case since it had localstorage data.

Comment: @SehoLee - Isn't iPhone's Safari supports localStorage? http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Comment: yes it does. but my desktop using firefox while iphone uses safari.